# Clarification of $G$-orbits acting on a finite set $X$ and subspaces of $\mathbb{C}[X].$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions

Suppose that $G$ acts on a finite set $X$, and define $\mathbb{C}[X]=\{f\mid f:X\to \mathbb{C}\}$.

I'm asked to show that every $G$-orbit in $X$ defines an invariant subspace in $\mathbb{C}[X]$, where the group representation of $G$ on $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is given by $(g\cdot f)(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$ for all $g\in G$.

However, I'm having difficulty understanding where each object lives, per se, and what the invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ actually are.

If I'm not mistaken, the $G$-orbits should be of the form $\mathcal{O}_x=\{f\in\mathbb{C}[X]\mid f(x)=x\}$, but I'm finding the representation given and the set $\mathbb{C}[X]$ to be abstract and difficult to understand.

This is homework, so I would ultimately like to prove the claim, but I would like some guidance on how to approach this.

Comment: You may find it easier to think of $\mathbb{C}[X] = \mathbb{Z}[X]\otimes \mathbb{C}$ as the space of formal sums $\sum_{x\in X} c_x [x]$ for arbitrary coefficients $c_x\in \mathbb{C}$. The ($\mathbb{C}$-linear) action of $G$ is then just $g.[x] = [g^{-1}x]$.

Comment: The orbit $O_x$ you have written down doesn't make sense, since the condition $f(x) = x$ doesn't make sense: the output of $f$ is a complex number, not an element of $X$.

Comment: @anomaly, are $[x]$ the basis elements of $\mathbb{C}[X]$?

Answer (score 1):

You can understand a function $f \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ as an assignment of a complex number to each element of $X$, in other words just writing a complex number next to each point of $X$. The $G$-action on $\mathbb{C}[X]$ must take some assignment and produce a new one. It makes sense that given an action of $G$ on $X$, there is a nice way to induce an action on the assignments $\mathbb{C}[X]$. An invariant function $f$ will be an assignment that is unchanged under the action of any $g \in G$, and so it makes sense that this is related to the orbits of $X$ under the $G$-action.

Take for example $X$ being four points, and $G = C_3$ (cyclic of order 3), with the action on $X$ joining three points into a cycle, while not touching the fourth. A generator $g$ of $G$ will act on an assignment by permuting the complex numbers attached to the cycle, while leaving the complex number attached to the isolated fourth point alone. (But check the direction of this cycle: it goes the opposite direction to what you think!)  If you want a function which is invariant under the whole of $G$, you need an assignment that doesn't change no matter what element of $G$ you hit it with, so it will have to assign the same number to each element of the cycle. The number assigned to the fourth point doesn't interact with the others, and so it can be varied independently.

So in this example it seems intuitive that the space of invariant functions is two-dimensional, since you have two complex numbers which may be varied independently. Does this picture give a good starting point on how to approach the question?

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see the picture. To clarify your $C_3$ example, if we had $5$ points instead of $4$, with $2$ of them fixed, would these conditions imply that the space of invariant functions is three dimensional? My reasoning is this: given an invariant function of $\mathbb{C}[X]$, it assigns the cycle a single value $z_1$, then one of the fixed points is assigned another value $z_2$, and finally the last fixed point takes a value $z_3.$ Is that correct, or do all fixed points take the same value?

Comment: Also, should I think of an invariant subspace of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ as $\{f\mid f(x)=z, z\in\mathbb{C}\}$?

Comment: The fixed points may take different values, since the function is still invariant, so in that case it looks like the space of invariant functions will be 3-dimensional. An invariant function $f$ satisfies $g \cdot f = g$ for all $g \in G$, and you should check that this forms a subspace.

Comment: Ok, things are much clearer now. However, why is an invariant function in this case going to satisfy $g\cdot f=g$? How exactly does this action output a complex number? In your first comment you mention that $\mathcal{O}_x=\{f\in\mathbb{C}[X]\mid f(x)=x\}$ doesn't make sense, but if it's the case that $\mathcal{O}_x$ is $\mathbb{C}[X]$ invariant, how does $g\cdot f=g$ make sense after we act on an element of $X$? I guess I'm confused as to what $(g\cdot f)(x)$ exactly is still.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $g \cdot f = f$.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine $X$ to be a set of students in a class. Instead of complex numbers, for the sake of ease in understanding, take the set of numbers $\{0,1,2,\ldots,\}$. A function on $X$ to this set of numbers  might be thought of scores awarded to the students in an exam.

Assume the students exchange the answerscripts among themselves (this is the action on $X$). Now the scores awarded is a different function. An orbit on $X$ is a subset of the set of students whose answer scripts get distributed among themselves.

Now a second professor aware of the paper swapping going on, awards scores to a
student as the sum of the scores awarded by the first professor, the sum being taken over the 'orbit' of students.

Can you see that this second professors score function is invariant?